# Start gvim at specific line, from a doubleclick on line in sumatraPDF

Tags: vim, gvim, latex

I use sumatraPDF and gVim to edit LaTeX files. Sumatra supposedly has a feature to open an editor at a specific line by the variable `%l`. As far as I can see, I can start gVim with the `+<num>` flag and it should start at the specific line.

But I can't seem to make that work. Sumatra opens gVim with the correct file (using `%f`) but it doesn't turn to the correct line.
I run this command: `gVim +%l --remote %f` (the file opens, the line does not seem to be affected).

I use gVim 7.3 in Windows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your arguments out of order, try this:

```
gvim --remote +%l %f
```

See:

```
:help --remote
```

From within Vim.